# PySide6 with QML and VTK9

Tags: python, qml, vtk, pyside6

I am trying to get a running example of a Qml application with PySide6 and an integrated VtkRenderWindow.
I tried [Qml-VTK-Python](https://github.com/dao-duc-tung/Qml-VTK-Python) but there is a problem with the generated
`rs_qml.py` from the pyside6-rcc when updating the packages to PySide6. And i dont want to mix the qt resource compiler.
Fork of the project: [Fork-Qml-VTK-Python](https://github.com/NewPony007/qml-vtk9-python310-PySide6).
Or perhaps anybody has a small running example? Must not be based on links project, I just need Vtk9 and PySide2 qith qml.
Best regards

What I did:

I updated the `PySide2` packages to `PySide6` in all files.

Changed the imports in `fboRender.py`

```
from PySide2.QtGui import (
    QCursor,
    QMouseEvent,
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject,
    QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat,
    QOpenGLFunctions,
    QWheelEvent,
)
```

to

```
from PySide6.QtGui import (
    QCursor,
    QMouseEvent,
    QOpenGLFunctions,
    QWheelEvent,
)
from PySide6.QtOpenGL import QOpenGLFramebufferObject, QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat
```

Changed in `funcs.py`

`"pyside2-rcc.exe"` to `"rcc.exe"`
and also the any `PySide2` to `PySide6`

i get than a Tracback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projekte\scripts_python\qml-vtk-python\src\views\rc_qml.py", line 108
    QT_RCC_MANGLE_NAMESPACE0(name), QT_RCC_MANGLE_NAMESPACE0(QT_NAMESPACE))
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
python-BaseException
```

Comment: Can't you just open the `rc_qml.py` and check it within your IDE? If it's too big, check it's `head` or `tail`.

Comment: I comment out in the `app.py` line33: ```compileResourceFiles(rcDir="src/views", outDir="src/views")```
and then commented in the `rc_qml.py` the line 107 where there seems to be a new line was made but the comment was not done correct  (mabye a bug of the pyrcc6) and also deleted the header but no luck: Error was then syntax error in line 1 of the `rc_qml.py`

Comment: Possible reason that the qrc (where only the `main.qml` is added as a resource) can not be compiled correct, is that the imported `QmlVtk 1.0` registered in lin 27 in `app.py`, where Fpo is the corresponding class, does not work?

Comment: I also tried to compile the qrc qith the pyside2-rcc, but also no luck :-(. Same Errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the qrc compiling error.
I had to change 
`pyside2-rcc.exe` to `pyside6-rcc.exe` 
`pyside2-rcc` to `pyside6-rcc` 
I am pretty sure i tried it, but nevertheless it works now. Another options was removing the rcc-compiling and load the `main.qml` direct (which was the only file in the qrc).

Rendering also works now (tested in linux) by replacing the OpenGLRenderWindow from gerneric to external.